# How do we tell apart metro tiles and desktop tiles?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, tiles

Windows 8 has metro apps and desktop app. Both of these have tiles. How do we tell whether a tile opens a metro app or a desktop app?

Comment: Because desktop tiles look like shortcuts and applications are full logos?  The 8.1 also makes a difference which one are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.1.

Comment: Maybe... Metro icons must be flat, 100% white, and simple. Desktop icons may be 3D, multicolored, with detailed logos.

Comment: I ask both for clarification and to help other people who might wonder later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metro icons must be flat, 100% white, and simple. Desktop icons may be 3D, multicolored, with detailed logos.